# 1-1 correspondence between maximal ideals and simple modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let us have a ring R. If R is commutative, then there is a 1-1 correspondence between
maximal ideals of R and simp-R given by the assignment I $\rightarrow$ R/I .


I have trouble prooving this. I already know, that for a module M it holds M is simple $\iff$ M $\cong$ R/I where I is maximal ideal. So that assignment makes sense. I need to show that it is surjective and injective, right?


Surjectivity is trivial - M simple $\implies$ M $\cong$ R/I where I is maximal ideal which exists because of Zorrn's lemma.


Injectivity is harder. In my notes it is done using annihilator, such that I = $Ann_{R}{(R/I)}$. Why is this true? and is it enough to show that then suppose I $\neq$ J for I, J ideals then $Ann_{R}{(R/I)}$ = I $\neq$ J = $Ann_{R}{(R/J)}$ and $Ann_{R}{(R/I)}$ $\neq$ $Ann_{R}{(R/J)}$ $\implies$ R/I $\neq$ R/J?

Comment: Since $a(r+I)=ar+I$, if $a$ annihilates $R/I$, then this product is $0$ (in $R/I$) for all $r$ in $R.$ If $a$ is in $I$, what can you conclude? Conversely, is there a particular choice of $r$ that allows you to say $a$ is in $I?$ You're actually working with isomorphism classes of simple modules. Can you now conclude that $R/I \cong R/J$ implies $I=J?$

Comment: Thanks. So I assume, that I can choose $r$=1. Then $a(1 + I) = a + I = 0$ (in classes), which implies $a \in I$. This is one inclusion, right? The other one would be that for all $i$ in $I$ $i(a + I) = ia + I$, but $ia \in I$, therefore it is equal to 0 and $i$ is in the annihilator. And then  $R/I \cong R/J \implies Ann_{R}(R/I) \cong Ann_{R}(R/I) \implies I \cong J$. I am not sure where I can switch from isomorphism to equation. And why is commutativity needed.

Comment: Isomorphic modules have the same annihilator, so you can imply $I=J.$ I'm not all that conversant with the noncommutative case. However, we have a lot of sharp people on the site. Perhaps one of them will provide an answer.

Comment: In the noncommutative case, the map (from maximal right ideals to isoclasses of simple right modules) is very non-injective. For $M_n(\mathbb Q)$ a field, for instance, there is only a single simple right module up to isomorphism, but there are infinitely many maximal right ideals.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $R$ is commutative, and that $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $R$ such that $R/I \cong R/J$ as $R$-modules. Then $I=J$.

Indeed, if $\varphi \colon R/I \to R/J$ is an isomorphism of $R$-modules, we write $\varphi(1+I)$ as $r+J$ for some $r \in R$, and then we note that for each $a \in J$,
$$
\varphi(a+I) = a\varphi(1+I) = ar+J = 0+J.
$$
(If $R$ is not commutative and we’re just dealing with, say, left $R$-modules, then the last equality may not hold.)
Thus, for each $a \in J$, injectivity of $\varphi$ gives us that $a+I = 0+I$, i.e. $a \in I$. Hence $J \subseteq I$, and the reverse inclusion can be proved using $\varphi^{-1}$.

Now, for a concrete example in the non-commutative case, consider the ring $R := \textsf{M}_{2 \times 2}(\Bbb R)$ and
$$
I := \begin{pmatrix} \Bbb R & 0 \\ \Bbb R & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad J := \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \Bbb R \\ 0 & \Bbb R \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $I$ and $J$ are maximal left ideals of $R$ such that $R/I \cong R/J$ as left $R$-modules.

Why? Well, first note that $M := \textsf{M}_{2 \times 1}(\Bbb R)$ is naturally a left $R$-module, and the functions $c_1,c_2  \colon R \to M$ sending a matrix to its first and second column are $R$-module homomorphisms ($c_1$ is just right multiplication with $\binom10$, and $c_2$ with $\binom01$) such that $\ker c_2 = I$ and $\ker c_1 = J$.

So, since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are surjective, it follows that $R/I \cong M \cong R/J$.
Finally, to prove the maximality, it suffices to show that $M$ is simple, and this follows from the fact that for each non-zero $x \in M$, $Rx = M$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\subset R$ are maximal ideals s.t. an $R$-module $M$ statisfies $R/\mathfrak{m}\cong M \cong R/\mathfrak{n}$ as $R$-modules. Let $(0:M)=\{ r\in R : rM=0\}$ denote the annhiliator of $M$. As $M\cong R/\mathfrak{m}$ as $R$-modules we have that $\mathfrak{m}\subset (0:M)$ as $M\neq 0$ clearly $(0:M)\neq R$ so by maximality $(0:M)=\mathfrak{m}$ do the same for $\mathfrak{n}$ to get the desired equality.